# visual basic tcp server:writing global functions with multiple forms

Tags: vb.net, sockets, visual-studio-2012, client-server

i wrote a program to implement a tcp ip server and it is working fine.i need to build a user interface having multiple forms.in my form1,i setup the socket server and its working fine.I need to access the function server.send() (server is the name of my function to send  data) in form 2 and form3. what all changes should i make to access it?

(i am using visual basic 2012 express edition)

Answer (score 1):

Put the subroutines and functions that you need throughout your project in a Module. If you add a Module to your project and paste your functions and subroutines into it, you'll be able to access those from all of the forms in the project.

Comment: the socket is created in first form. does it kept open in second form? can i send data if i declared it in module? can you provide any link or sample code?

Comment: If the socket is declared in the Module, then it will keep alive until the object is destroyed. I don't have any sample code handy, but I did find a tutorial that goes through some of the concepts of socket programming in VB.Net. [Client and Server Socket Programming](http://checktechno.blogspot.com/2013/04/tutorial-client-server-using-visual.html) - I hope that helps.